# Initialise geckoWebBrowser Exception for C#

Tags: c#, geckofx

My program below throws an exception.

Program.cs is as follows:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("D:\\xulrunner\\");
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
```

Form1.cs is as follows:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("D:\\xulrunner\\");

        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");

    }
```

Translated from Chinese, the exception is as follows:

"System.__ComObject" cannot convert Interface type `"Gecko.nsIWebNavigation"`

The exception is thrown in the following code:

```
public ChromeContext()
{
    using (var appShallSvc = Xpcom.GetService2<nsIAppShellService>(Contracts.AppShellService))
    {
        webNav = appShallSvc.Instance.CreateWindowlessBrowser(true).AsComPtr(); //this is where the exception is thrown

        webNav.Instance.LoadURI("chrome://global/content/alerts/alert.xul", 0, null, null, null);

    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are using an incompatible version of XULRunner. Versions of the Geckofx and XULRunner must match.

Comment: i used XULRunner is xulrunner-41.0b9.en-US.win32.

Comment: It is very important that the geckofx you use matches the xulrunner/firefox major version.

Comment: it's right! but i can't find to  gecko45 with xulrunner version.But i used to gecko33 is ok thank you very much！

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely

Comment: @WF Were you able to find the correct xulrunner version for gecko45?

Answer (score 0):

For older versions, you need to match your GeckoFX release with the exact correct version of xulrunner.

Check your version here: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx/wiki/Version_lists

Download xulrunner here: https://releases.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/releases/

But this has been greatly simplified with version 45.0:

> For Geckofx 45.0 and newer publishing has been moved to a nuget
>   package model, which includes the both the geckofx files and the
>   required firefox files.